# Can't checkout to a new branch - ansible git

Tags: git, ansible

I am trying to create a playbook where i can checkout to any branch just by changing a variable. The git section of the playbook is:

```
- name: Clone repository
  git: 
    repo: "{{ repo_url }}"
    dest: /some_path
    key_file: some_path_to_a_file
    version: "{{ repo_tag }}"
    force: yes
```

I first used `repo_tag=master` and it worked. Then I created a new branch called dev and tried with `repo_tag=dev`. It says that it can't checkout to that tag. The issue seems to be that the module is not fetching before doing the checkout.

What am i doing wrong on my play?

Edit:
As a temporary workaround i am just deleting the repository folder before the cloning, but that forces a clone even when it is not necessary.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I believe this is a bug in ansible. Even when I push a change to master and rerun the playbook, it doesn't pick up the update.

Comment: It is not happening to me anymore after switching to ansible2. Which version are you using?